# How to get a reference to a Module?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to encapsulate some code using the Module Pattern. The problem is I can't get a reference to it. I get the following error

> Message: 'plannerTab.getConfig' is
>   null or not an object Line: 14 Char: 5
>   Code: 0

**Code**

```
/*  Document Ready */
$(function ()
{
    /* get config */
    var config = plannerTab.getConfig;
});



/* Module */
var plannerTab = (function ()
{
    var config = {
        tableId: '#plannerTable'

    };

   return
   {
      getConfig: config
   };

})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're a victim of automatic semicolon insertion.

this:

```
return
{
  getConfig: config
};
```

should be written like:

```
return {
  getConfig: config
};
```

Comment: wow. So by putting the bracket after return on a newline it auto inserts a semicolon?

Comment: @chobo: Yes, you've got a valid statement `return` followed by a line break followed by another valid (though odd) bit of code, so a semicolon is inserted. Somehow the interpreters see your object as a Block containing a variable with a label before it. As such, it considers them to be 2 separate valid statements, and inserts the semicolon. That is an extremely simplified (and clumsy) description of ASI, but you get the idea. That's why in javascript it is considered good practice to have your opening `{` on the same line instead of the next.

Comment: Thanks patrick for the excellent description patrick. I think I am going to change my code formatting. Just out of curiosity am I using the module pattern wrong? You mentioned something was odd?

Comment: @chobo: By "odd" I meant the interpreters interpretation of the statement after the `return`. It doesn't see it as an object with a property, but rather a Block with a label and a variable. Your code is fine, except I don't think that it's really a module pattern unless you return a function that closes around some local variable. Right now you're not really benefiting from the immediately invoked function. The exact code could be duplicated with simple object literals. But maybe this isn't your entire code. :o)

Comment: No, it's just a simple sample. I originally had only object literals, but tacked on the module due to namespacing conflicts in regards to future development. I could of made my literal names more explicit, but wanted to try this out.